# Unknown type name Error Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiview

It's giving the UNKNOWN TYPE NAME error. I had imported "billSummary" class as well, but don't know why xcode giving this error.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "customiseForItems.h"
    #import "billSummary.h"

    @interface itemsInParty : UITableViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>{
        IBOutlet customiseForItems *tblCell;
        IBOutlet UIToolbar *billSummaryTool;

        CGFloat percValue;
        billSummary *billSummaryToShow;        //ERROR UNKNOWN TYPE NAME BILL SUMMARY
        UIAlertView *alertForPercentage;
        NSMutableArray *selectedEntriesPath;
        BOOL descTapped;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write `@class billSummary;` instead of  `#import "billSummary.h"`

Try like this it will be helpful to you.

Comment: YEs, It helped. Can I ask the reason why to use @class instead of #import?

Comment: Sure. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743432/import-header-files)

Answer (score 0):

one possible reason is:

billSummary.h

```
@interface billSummaryMisspelled : ParentClass
@end
```

billSummary.m

```
@implementation billSummaryMisspelled
@end
```

your file name != to you class name

you can use forward class declaration to skip the error,

```
@class billSummary;
```

instead of #import